# How to center the element at the same time keep the size in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styles

Currently I have a layout like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    foreach ($card_list as $key => $card) {
        echo '<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3">';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

This will generate a card like this, if the size is md

```
box1 box2 box3 box4
```

However, since the `<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3">` is fix , there is some empty space if e.g. I have only 3 box . As the number of box is dynamic , can I center the box base on the number e.g. if I have only 3

```
offset box1  box2  box3 offset
```

Instead of

```
 box1  box2  box3  empty area
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: just wrap a div with class container around it

Comment: try add this css    


`.row {display:table; margin : 0 auto}`

Comment: try add the css but both left and right has so may padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to centering a column  in Bootstrap 3:

## Approach 1 (offsets):

The first approach uses Bootstrap's own offset classes so it requires no change in markup and no extra CSS. The key is to **set an offset equal to half of the remaining size of the row**. So for example, a column of size 2 would be centered by adding an offset of 5, that's `(12-2)/2`.
In markup this would look like:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5"></div>
</div>
```

Now, there's an obvious drawback for this method, **it only works for even column sizes**, so only .col-X-2, .col-X-4, col-X-6, col-X-8 and col-X-10 are supported.

---

## Approach 2 (the old margin:auto)

You can **center any column size** by using the proven `margin: 0 auto;` technique, you just need to take care of the floating that is added by Bootstrap's grid system. I recommend defining a custom CSS class like the following:

```
.col-centered{
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Now you can add it to any column size at any screen size and it will work seamlessly with Bootstrap's responsive layout :
**Note:** With both techniques you could skip the `.row` element and have the column centered inside a `.container` but you would notice a minimal difference in the actual column size because of the padding in the container class.

---

**Update:**
Since v3.0.1 Bootstrap has a built-in class named center-block that uses margin: 0 auto but is missing float:none. You can add that to your CSS to make it work with the grid system.